# Подскажите как сделать из этого выбор ролей как нас крине? Во фронте не шарю а сделать надо к приложению

Tags: javascript, html

```html
// функция конструирует страницу для добавления юзера
function showAddUserPanel() {
    // вызываем функцию для построения вкладок
    showTabs();

    // Конструкция заголовка таблицы
    $("#allUsersSubHeader").children().remove();
    $(
        "<h3>&nbsp;Add new user</h3>"
    ).appendTo("#allUsersSubHeader");

    // Конструкция формы с добавлением юзера
    $("#tableInputArea").children().remove();
    $(
        "<div class=\"row\">\n" +
        "                            <div class=\"col-4\"></div>\n" +
        "                            <div class=\"col-4\">\n" +
        "                                <form id='formNewUser'>\n" +
        "                                    <table class=\"table bg-white align-middle table-borderless\">\n" +
        "                                        <tbody>\n" +
        "                                        <tr>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <label for=\"firstName_add\">Enter name:</label>\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" id=\"firstName_add\" name=\"firstName\">\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                        </tr>\n" +
        "                                        <tr>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <label for=\"lastName_add\">Enter Last Name:</label>\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" id=\"lastName_add\" name=\"lastName\">\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                        </tr>\n" +
        "                                        <tr>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <label for=\"age_add\">Enter age:</label>\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" id=\"age_add\" name=\"age\">\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                        </tr>\n" +
        "                                        <tr>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <label for=\"email_add\">Enter Email:</label>\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"email\" id=\"email_add\" name=\"email\">\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                        </tr>\n" +
        "                                        <tr id=\"rolesCheckboxes\">\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <label for=\"password_add\">Enter Password:</label>\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                            <div class=\"text-center\">\n" +
        "                                                <input class=\"form-control\" type=\"password\" id=\"password_add\" name=\"password\">\n" +
        "                                            </div>\n" +
        "                                        </tr>\n" +
        
        "                                        <tr>\n" +
        "                                            <td class=\"text-center btn-lg\" colspan=\"2\">\n" +
        "                                                <input class=\"btn btn-success\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"addNewUserFunction()\" value=\"ADD NEW USER\"/>\n" +
        "                                            </td>\n" +
        "                                        </tr>\n" +
        "                                        </tbody>\n" +
        "                                    </table>\n" +
        "                                </form>\n" +
        "                            </div>\n" +
        "                            <div class=\"col-4\"></div>\n" +
        "                        </div>"
    ).appendTo("#tableInputArea");
    // формируем список ролей с чекбоксами
    findRolesList().then(r => r.map(role => {
        $("#rolesCheckboxes").after(
            "<tr><select class=\"container-fluid\">\n" +
            "<label for=\"" + role.role + "\" class=\"form-select\">" + role.role.replace("ROLE_ADMIN", "Admin").replace("ROLE_USER", "User") + "</label>\n" +
            "</select>" +
            "<select class=\"text-center\">" +
            "<input name=\"roles\" id=\"" + role.role + "\" class=\"form-check-input\" type=\"checkbox\"  multiple value=\"" + role.id + "\"/></select></tr>")
    }));
}

// Конструкция вкладок
function showTabs() {
    $("#adminPanelNavTabs").children().remove();
    $(
        "<tr>" +
        "<th>" +
        "<ul class=\"nav nav-tabs fw-normal\">" +
        "<li class=\"nav-item\">" +
        "<a class=\"nav-link\" onclick=\"showAllUsers()\">Users table</a>" +
        "</li>" +
        "<li class=\"nav-item\">" +
        "<a class=\"nav-link active\" onclick=\"showAddUserPanel()\">New user</a>" +
        "</li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "</th>" +
        "</tr>"
    ).appendTo("#adminPanelNavTabs");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте тег select:

```
 <select>
     <option>Role 1</option>
     <option>Role 2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: еще необходимо добавить аттрибут ```multiple```

Comment: @Burr_Dl               type="checkbox" вообще убрать получается?

Comment: @Burr_DI если можете объясните по подробнее

Comment: @СергейЗ. селект предоставляет выбор одного элемента опшин из списка. Инпут чекбокс позволяет выбирать несколько элементов (https://ru.code-basics.com/languages/html/lessons/checkbox) - уточните сколько ролей можно выбрать?

Comment: @СергейЗ  Может быть вам подойдет вариант от @soledar10.(http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/multiple#:~:text=%D0%90%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%20multiple%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE,%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E.)

Comment: @Burr_DI Должно быть две роли Admin и User я прикрепил весь js код свой просто завис именно на ролях с чекбоксами как то проще но требование именно как на скрине

Comment: @СергейЗ. тогда наверное лучше подойдет инпут с типо радио(https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio), но что с селектом что с инпутом придется посидеть-поработать над стилями(видом)

Comment: @Burr_DI спасибо буду пробовать